# how to create a simple api to execute tests by multiple users in parallel

Tags: java, junit, parallel-processing

I would like to create a rest api service in java that will run Jsystem test scenarios by user request.

i need somehow to be able to receive some test parameters , parameters for SUT file, and a scenario, and somehow execute it as a test suite

is there a Jsystem mechanism that support this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a CI server. There are many. 
One of them is Jenkins, which is most well known in the Java world.

Most  of CI servers have UI and REST API to start builds, they can get build parameters from users etc.
You will have to configure your build to run the unit tests.

Jenkins: https://jenkins.io

Bamboo: https://xebialabs.com/technology/bamboo/

A list of others: https://xebialabs.com/the-ultimate-devops-tool-chest/continuous-integration/